Do scriptures prohibit Kshatriyas from transplanting and ploughing land?
Do any smriti prohibit Kshatriyas from farming or cultivation?

Texts like the Bhagavad Gita (which is classified as a smriti, and is anyway authoritative) generally count agriculture as a task of the vaishyas, and say that the divisions between each caste's roles are strict (18.38-47).
However, the Vishnu Purana offers a caveat:

Aurva answered and said, "Attentively listen to the duties which I shall describe as those severally of the Brahman, the Kshatriya, the Vaiśya, and the Śúdra."
[...]
"Brahmá, the great parent of creation, gave to the Vaiśya the occupations of commerce and agriculture, and the feeding of flocks and herds, for his means of livelihood."
[...]
"In times of distress the peculiar functions of the castes may be modified, as you shall hear. A Brahman may follow the occupations of a Kshatriya or a Vaiśya; the Kshatriya may adopt those of the Vaiśya; and the Vaiśya those of the Kshatriya: but these two last should never descend to the functions of the Śúdra, if it be possible to avoid them; and if that be not possible, they must at least shun the functions of the mined castes.
[3.8]

Of course, what "times of distress" are is a bit subjective, but it does seem as though it is permissible for Kshatriyas to farm and plough land in emergencies.
